# How to format and print a text file in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to print the below bill using Samsung Mobile Print application. I formatted it (using String.format(%25s,itemName)) and the spaces between them are equal while viewing the file in google drive or OfficeSuite app. But when I open it in any printing app,or even a text editor in mobile, the content is totally distorted and the formatting done is lost like the below text.

1. Chicken Chettinad Half    70    1   70
2. Chicken Chettinad Full   130    1  130
3. Andhra Chicken Curry      70    1   70
4. Andhra Chicken Curry     130    1  130
5. Chapati                   10    1   10

I want it to look like the below text.

```
1. Chicken Chettinad Half    70    1   70

2. Chicken Chettinad Full   130    1  130

3. Andhra Chicken Curry      70    1   70

4. Andhra Chicken Curry     130    1  130

5. Chapati                   10    1   10
```

Comment: When you print with your code to text file and then open this .txt, is the formatting preserved, i.e. does your output string contains correct spacing ?

Comment: I uploaded the text file to the Google Drive and I can see the formatting is preserved, but if I open the file using any text editor,or when I click print it goes to the print application with the distorted format like the first example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your text file to maintain correct indentation between columns you could provide maximum width for each column and alignment in your `String.format` call.
For instance this code :

```
        String[] name = {"Chapati", "Chicken Chettinad Full"};
        int[] price = {70, 130};
        int[] quantity = {1, 1};

        String res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; ++i) {
            res += String.format("%2d. %-23s %4d %4d %4d%n", i + 1, name[i],
                        price[i], quantity[i], price[i] * quantity[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("res = \n" + res);
```

will print output :

```
1. Chapati                   70    1   70
2. Chicken Chettinad Full   130    1  130
```